# any idea how to update python PIP on a windows box?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pip

`pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't work because the windows FS is brain damaged and won't let you delete an open file.

I've tried setting my environment to the virtualenv that I want to update and then running from a different pip, but that fails with:

```
(jm) E:\python\jm>c:\Python26\Scripts\pip install --upgrade pip
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pip
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 0.7.1
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
  Running setup.py install for pip
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
    Installing pip-script.py script to c:\Python26\Scripts
    Installing pip.exe script to c:\Python26\Scripts
    Installing pip.exe.manifest script to c:\Python26\Scripts
    Installing pip-2.6-script.py script to c:\Python26\Scripts
    Installing pip-2.6.exe script to c:\Python26\Scripts
    Installing pip-2.6.exe.manifest script to c:\Python26\Scripts
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 120, in main
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 165, in run
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg\pip\req.py", line 1251, in install
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg\pip\req.py", line 466, in commit_uninstall
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg\pip\req.py", line 1549, in commit
  File "c:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 216, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 216, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 221, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 219, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\mark\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-gvsove-uninstall\\python26\\scripts\\pip.exe'

Storing complete log in C:\Users\mark\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log

(jm) E:\python\jm>dir c:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\temp\pip-gvsove-uninstall\python26\scripts
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 74E4-FE9F

 Directory of c:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\temp\pip-gvsove-uninstall\python26\scripts

12/07/2010  11:32 AM    <DIR>          .
12/07/2010  11:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/14/2010  05:54 PM             7,168 pip.exe
               1 File(s)          7,168 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  22,824,603,648 bytes free

(jm) E:\python\jm>del c:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\temp\pip-gvsove-uninstall\python26\scripts\pip.exe
```

I'm hoping someone else has figured out a way around this.  Its no problem on linux....

Comment: I got the error, but the upgrade did in fact work.

Comment: It's so great to see that this is still a problem 3.5 years later with the latest Python 2.7.10 and pip 7.1.2 on Windows. None of the suggestions below fix it. Super awesome.

Comment: The solution that worked for me is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17687817/2412846). In short: you're using pip to update pip, but as it is running it can't overwrite itself. Copy it somewhere and run it from there.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`easy_install -U pip`

:-)

Comment: That was too simple.  I didn't know that easy_install did understood virtualenvs.  Thanks.

Comment: Each virtualenv gets setuptools installed into it as well as pip - handy to know about for packages which don't currently install cleanly from source on Windows (without tinkering) such as PIL, for which easy_install will use the .exe installer (at least until pip gains this capability).

Comment: `easy_install` is an old tool, that is deprecated. Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead.

Answer (score 67):

Run pip as a script, using python as the main executable.

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: Times have changed and I think this is the new way to do this.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what the PIP developers decided to recommend when they discussed this bug: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1299

Comment: This one is Good.

Answer (score 19):

[UPDATE 2015-11-15] This post is obsolete and out of date. Current best practice is [according to pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/#id6) is to use the following:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

It's not necessary to use [`easy_install`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) from [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools). The recommended procedure to update pip, from the [pip-installer](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer) page is to use [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

> To install or **upgrade** pip, securely download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

You can use the following in a [Bash shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) like [msysgit's Git Bash](http://msysgit.github.com/).

```
user@machine ~$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
```

Use the `-L` option to follow redirects. Recently GitHub changed the url for raw content, so [the old raw `get-pip.py` url](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) has been [redirected](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and on the pip website [the url was changed](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). If successful, you should see the following:

```
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1309k  100 1309k    0     0   364k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  366k
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=4d4fb4b69df6731c7aeaadd6300bc1f2
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

You can modify this for the Windows command line, but first if you don't have libcurl, [download a Windows binary from Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). You'll want to scroll all the way to the bottom and get [Günter Knauf's current official Win32 binary (currently 7.29)](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.29.0/dist-w32/curl-7.29.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-idn-static-bin-w32.zip) and unzip it. Don't worry about it being 32-bit versus 64-bit. Just make sure you get the one with all the bells and whistles (ssl, zlib, etc.). Now navigate to the folder where you downloaded curl, probably `c:\Users\<you>\Downloads`, open the extracted folder, probably `curl-7.29.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-idn-static-bin-w32`, and you should find `curl.exe`. Yay! Now in a windows shell type this after the prompt (which will have your username instead of `myusername`), replacing `path\to\Curl\` with the path to the downloaded `curl.exe` file.

```
C:\Users\myusername> path\to\Curl\curl.exe -kL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

You need the `-k` option to allow curl to access the secure GitHub pip site without certs. Also, thanks [Piotr Dobrogost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95735/piotr-dobrogost) for telling me about Windows pipes, `|`, which saves the step of saving the file.

If you already have the latest version of pip you will get the following message:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1309k  100 1309k    0     0   369k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  371k
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Also works just fine in virtualenvs.

Comment: You can use pipes in Windows. :)

Comment: This doesn't upgrade -- it says "requirements already up-to-date: pip" if pip is already installed.

Comment: @remram can you please post your terminal session. This has not been my experience. I have used this method many, many times to upgrade pip to the latest, but I have not seen the message you are describing. Are you still having issues. I am happy to troubleshoot with you.

Comment: @remram Ah, maybe you were foiled by the change in url for raw files. Try it with the new links on the pip website - I've also updated them here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Right Click Anaconda Prompt (Run as Admin)

```
>> conda update pip
```

(If you are using Anaconda. PS: It worked for me)

Answer (score -1):

Hey i Just able to Upgrade PIP on Python 36 with Following Command in CMD

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

[image: CMD : Upgrading PIP in Python 36]

Answer (score -2):

`pip install pip --upgrade`

[image] worked for me

Note: Make sure you are running command Prompt in administrator mode