# "Access is denied" while upgrading pip.exe on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

pip asked me to upgrade with a message:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I ran that command and I get an exception that pip cannot uninstall the old version because access to my user directory is denied:

```
    Collecting pip
    Downloading pip-7.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
      100% |################################| 1.1MB 292kB/s
    Installing collected packages: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 7.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-7.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.0.1
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 297, in run

    root=options.root_path,
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 633, in install
    requirement.commit_uninstall()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 734, in commit_uninstall
    self.uninstalled.commit()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 153, in commit
    rmtree(self.save_dir)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get

    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 89, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 101, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
    WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\chris\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-ossyhh-uninstall\\python27\\scripts\\pip.exe'
```

I'm running Windows 8.1, but I've had this same Error on another machine running Windows 7. It doesn't seem to stop the installation of the new version, but I do end up with pip folders left in my temp directory. Does anyone know why this happens or how I can correct it?

**Edit1:**
Oddly, running the upgrade with admin privlidges throws a **new** exception:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 302, in _get_launcher
result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'`
```

And fails the upgrade entirely.

**Edit2:**
The only way to get around this issue does seem to be using easy_install to upgrade pip (either the -U or -m options), but it seems like a problem to me if pip can't upgrade itself, when its intended (and stated) functionality is to do so.

Comment: Are you running from a command prompt without administrator privileges?

Comment: That could be an issue too ! Run as Admin

Comment: I think I read that this is an issue with permissions set on the appdata\local\temp folder. You might try checking the permissions on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [any idea how to update python PIP on a windows box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379970/any-idea-how-to-update-python-pip-on-a-windows-box)

Comment: @Noob Yes I looked at that question, but it's from 2010, and doesn't really answer the question. I don't think I should have to use easy_install when pip explicitly tells me it can upgrade itself.

Comment: Looks like my profile has all permissions for this folder, except "special permissions" (admin doesn't have that one either). I will try running the command prompt instance with admin privileges, but doesn't it seem odd that I would need that for my own user folder?

Comment: Still a problem with Python 2.7.10 and pip 7.0.1 (upgrading to 7.1.2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is apparently because you are running `pip.exe` to upgrade itself.  So the `pip.exe` to be deleted is actually running at the time.  The fix is to use a slightly different command line:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This is from this [bug report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2863) (though there are others):

> •  Access is denied: '... pip.exe'  is because you're upgrading pip
>   using the  pip.exe  wrapper which gets replaced in the upgrade. On
>   Windows you can't replace in-use executables/DLLs. You should use 
>   python -m pip install --upgrade pip . IIRC this is noted in the
>   documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem recently on a windows 7 machine.  I ran command prompt as administrator (from your comments), and then typed in `pip install --upgrade pip`.

It returned error messages out the wazoo, but then when I tried to do it again (`pip install --upgrade pip`), it told me pip was already up to date.  Then `pip -V` told me I had pip 7.0.3.

No idea what is happening.  Trying to get python packages on windows seems very difficult.  Hope that was helpful.

Also, I'm using python 3.5, which may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue while installing matplotlib using the pip-7.1.2 version so I upgraded it to pip 9.0.1.

However while updating it gave me an error of access denied to pip.exe but when I checked the version using pip -v it was updated. And I simply run pip install matplotlib. It worked for me.

```
D:\Users\703186511>pip install --upgrade pip
```

or try

```
D:\Users\703186511>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
D:\Users\703186511>pip -V
D:\Users\703186511>pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem . I simply used the SUDO command on my mac terminal and it worked. Below is the terminal output.

sudo pip install -U pip

```
Anuvrats-MacBook-Air:~ anuvrattiku$ pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
Anuvrats-MacBook-Air:~ anuvrattiku$ **sudo pip install -U pip**
Password:
The directory '/Users/anuvrattiku/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/anuvrattiku/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 272kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
Successfully installed pip-8.0.2
Anuvrats-MacBook-Air:~ anuvrattiku$
```