# Python voice recognition installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, voice-recognition

I am trying to install the python voice recognition library. Currently am using Python 3.5.2 and followed [python speech recognition document](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/):

I have used following steps as in the document:

- **Python** 2.6, 2.7, or 3.3+ (required)
- **PyAudio** 0.2.9+ (required only if you need to use microphone input, Microphone)
- **PocketSphinx** (required only if you need to use the Sphinx recognizer, recognizer_instance.recognize_sphinx)
- **FLAC encoder** (required only if the system is not x86-based
  Windows/Linux/OS X)

After that I have used below command

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

While installing I got the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35
32\lib\site
-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 605, in unpack_file
untar_file(filename, location)
File "c:\users\nisarahmed.h\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 577, in untar_file
with open(path, 'wb') as destfp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'C:\\Users\\NISARA~1.H\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-build-zjx5yab7\\SpeechRecognition\\SpeechRecognition.egg-info/.
dropbox.attr'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the problem could be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31172719/2677943

Comment: I tried that and getting same error

Comment: This works for me:  `sudo python -m pip install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: @YanKingYin The issue related to the anti-virus. After stopped running anti-virus, the same code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that McAfee antivirus blocked the installation. After pausing the McAfee, the installation completed successfully.

```
:\USERS\NISARAHMED.H\APPDATA\LOCAL\PROGRAMS\PYTHON\PYTHON35-32\PYTHON.EXE
C:\USERS\NISARA~1.H\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\PIP-BUILD-WPUQP6JM\SPEECHRECOGNITION\
SPEECHRECOGNITION.EGG-INFO\.DROPBOX.ATTR User-defined Rules:Dropbox Blocking
Action blocked : Create
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with root user. Make sure you are logged in with super user. As:
sudo pip install SpeechRecognition

Comment: Yes, I have admin rights. After that I found the issue that system antivirus blocked the installation. Find below my answer.