# Pip Python Installation Issues

Tags: python, pip

I'm pretty new to the community, and new to python. I know the basics. But now I'm trying to download third party modules via pip but everything I do regarding pip displays an error. I know that pip comes with python seeing as the pip file is there.

[image: photo of pip in python file]

I am running python 3.6 and windows 10. I have downloaded pip off the internet also but when I try to run the program it says already downloaded. The first time I ran it it said that it was downloading and successfully downloaded so I'm kind of lost.

[image: photo of pip download code and what it said when ran]

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you type pip on the command line? And what do you see when you type: echo %path%. Also, I'd recommend you try downloading anaconda. It's likely to be easier for you to get started with.

Comment: sounds like it's already properly installed... pip is a program called from a system terminal not from a python terminal. open up a command prompt and type `pip -h` see what happpens

Comment: when I type pip -h it says access denied. Also, thank you for getting back to me so quickly!

Comment: can you post full error text?

Comment: the full error text on command prompt? all it says on Command Prompt is Access Denied. on idle pip -h just produces pip not defined

Comment: a box pops up and it says this app cant run on your pc

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's already properly installed. pip is a program called from a system terminal, not from a Python prompt. Open up a command prompt and type `pip -h` see what happens. If this does not print out the help page on how to use pip, and instead you get an error to the effect of:

```
"pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

You then need to point Windows where to find the program (pip.exe) by adding your Python scripts folder `C:\...\Python36-32\Scripts\` to your environment `PATH` variable. To do this, open the Start menu and search for "environment variables". Open the dialogue and find one named `PATH` (case doesn't matter). If it doesn't exist, create it. Edit the value and add the file path to the scripts folder to the end using `;` as a separator.

As per your comment, if you are getting an access denied windows error [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885745/3220135) answer from another question may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need need to be sure either your powershell is being run as administrator, or by creating a virtual environment.

The Installing Packages docs have a great overview, and instructions.
https://packaging.python.org/installing/#use-pip-for-installing