# Error during Pip Django Install

Tags: python, django, web-applications

Yesterday, I installed Django on my aunt's pc and it worked wonders. Today, I'm trying to install it on my pc, and it gives the following error:

```
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_f
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'c:\\program files\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytz'
```

I'm counting on you guys. I'm new to this world, and I'm willing to learn.
P.D.: "Acceso denegado" = "Access denied"

Comment: it only means python does not have rights to create dirs as shown by the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)