# Failed to import the TensorFlow module

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have problems with my installation of tensorflow.
I got a [mrry/tensorflow_self_check.py](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c)  script and made some adjustment [MurDoDePar / tensorflow_self_check.py](https://github.com/MurDoDePar/TestTensorflowJava/blob/master/TestTensorflowJava/src/org/murdodepar/test/tensorflow_self_check.py)

I get this result:

```
- Python version is 3.6.
- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow
*** Failed to import the TensorFlow module.
- Find msvcp140.dll
- Find cudart64_91.dll
- Find nvcuda.dll
- Find cuDNN 7 cudnn64_7.dll.

*** ERROR Liste
    - Failed to import the TensorFlow module.
```

If I make the order `pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow` I have errors :

```
C:\Users\domin>pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow_gpu-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tensorflow-tensorboard<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached tensorflow_tensorboard-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
...OK
  Using cached setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, html5lib, numpy, markdown, wheel, werkzeug, setuptools, protobuf, bleach, futures, tensorflow-tensorboard, absl-py, tensorflow-gpu
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\users\domin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\domin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
```

I'm stuck can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have permission to install it.

You could try to run it using the python executable, as explained in [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)

Or you could try to run CMD as Administrator, then try installing again.

Comment: thank you
I installed
python -m pip install mitmproxy
pip install Django
python -m pip install
launched pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow with cmd, and then press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER., i had the same problem.
I am radu account that I had 2 python that turned in the background I killed both and the installation is passed.

Comment: Yes
thank you, I did not find how to close the question.

Comment: There should be a check mark below the score of this question you can click to mark it as solved.