# I can't install new packages / Python asks me to upgrade with its new version, but it doesn't work neither

Tags: python, installation, upgrade

I tried to install new packages, for example by executing :
    ! pip install ggplot

But when I do this, I get an error :

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\brewer2mpl'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I tried to execute as they ask :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then I get this error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<ipython-input-8-93493bbcf27f>, line 1)
  File "<ipython-input-8-93493bbcf27f>", line 1
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there anyone who knows where I did wrong ?

Comment: You typed in a command-line command *into a Python shell*. It's not Python syntax, it's shell syntax.

Comment: The upgrade message is just a warning, 'should consider' is not the same thing as 'must'. There is a PermissionError there, where you can't write to the `C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages` folder. That's not an error upgrading `pip` will solve, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Vicrobot: they are on Windows, there is no 'root user' there. And I'm pretty sure pip 10.0.1 is fine, I'm not sure what you mean by there being a bug in that version.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of another question with the same problem: a `PermissionDenied` error when using `pip install` with Anaconda, on Windows.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much !

Comment: Do you speak about this subject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows ? Because I tried also to write "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" in cmd, but it doesn't work either

Comment: (even if I change the directory to Python's directory)

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t have a Windows system at the moment to test on. I don’t know.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answers.