# Access is denied when trying to pip install a package on Windows

Tags: python, windows

How to set path for python 3.7.0?
I tried the every possible way but it still shows the error!

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]
>
> Access is denied: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1.dist-info\entry_points.txt'
>
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)

Answer (score 29):

Add `--user` to the command.

eg:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Comment: Please add more explanation about your answer

Answer (score 17):

Append the `--user` modifier to your command as suggested in the error.

> `--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

More: [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Comment: Will this cause problems for other users if the modules are only installed local to one user?

Comment: It will if the code is propagated after unit testing. It won't work for other users.

Answer (score 14):

Run your command Prompt on Admin-Mode in Windows,it will stop throwing errors for user-rights.

Steps:

1. On Windows, type "Cmd" on searchbox to search for command prompt.
2. When "Command Prompt" search result appears,right-click>Run as Administrator.

Comment: This also fixed the issue I had for installing a python lib from a setup.py script. `python setup.py install` had to be run via command prompt on the admin mode..

Answer (score 11):

You can add --user in the end of your command. This works well in my case!

```
--user
```

My example:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

Comment: how does this provide anything not already covered in other answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543327/4298200 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just try on Administrator cmd

```
pip install --user numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your command prompt on admin mode.
type :

`cd\`

then type:

`cd [Your python location path]`

on mycomputer it's:
`cd C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`
then type:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

You can follow this guide~
https://datatofish.com/upgrade-pip/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

After installing Python for all the users, wanted to install Django.

For that I've gone to the Command Prompt (without using Admin mode) and

```
pip.exe install django==2.2
```

This prompted the following message

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]
>   Access is denied: 'c:\program
>   files\python37\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3.dist-info\entry_points.txt'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

The way I've used to solve it was to add **--user** in the end of the command, just like the prompt message suggests («Consider using the `--user`»).

```
pip.exe install django==2.2 --user
```

Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The question was for windows but if any linux users that stumbled here (like me) : Permission Error Persists by adding `--user` in my virtualenv on Ubuntu 19 when I want to generate **requirements.txt**. Also, I can't `pip install --user` as well since I'm in an virtualenv. My solution was just using `sudo pip3 install pipreqs` to install another pipreqs for super user.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to throw an answer out here because I've been against a rock wall since upgrading to python 3.18.  Pip install  stopped working with a module error which was rectified with py -m pip install  --user.  *but* I would still get this permissions error.  I uninstalled, reinstalled, and downgraded Python and Pip.  I ran command prompt as administrator.  None of it worked.

The only thing that worked was to pip download  and then pip install the package from my c:/ drive.  Totally BS workaround, but if you'r as stuck as I was it works.