# pip install --upgrade pip in a venv throws error on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I'm getting following error when I run the command `pip install --upgrage pip` in an active venv created with `python -m venv venv` on Windows OS.

[image]

And, once run this command(`pip install --upgrade pip`) the second time I try any pip command, I receive another error...

> \venv\Scripts\pip.exe_*main*_.py", line 4, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

I have tried python versions 3.7.8 and 3.8.5

**This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115744/access-is-denied-when-trying-to-pip-install-a-package-on-windows) doesn't solve my problem, so Please don't close my question.**

Comment: Are you in an env?

Comment: Yes, I'm running this command in activated venv

Comment: ```pip install --upgrade pip --user```? if it is helpful i will post it as an answer

Comment: Please reply @DevLoverUmar

Comment: python has more permissions has inside your venv, try running CMD as admin

Comment: @AryanMishra Now, getting this error ...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Ok let me try but is there any better solution?

Comment: maybe try `pip install --user --upgrage pip`

Comment: @DevLoverUmar Hmmm... if you get the error no module named ```pip``` something is fishy maybe try @BlackThunder's solution.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed no, cmd in Admin mode is not working as well

Comment: Have a look at this forum, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115744/access-is-denied-when-trying-to-pip-install-a-package-on-windows

Comment: @AryanMishra that thread don't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to close all running IDEs or Jupyter notebook, and for the second error try using pip3 instead of pip.
`pip3 install --user <package_name>`
or
`python -m pip3 install --user --upgrade pip`

This question has a similar error, might be helpful: [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)