# I get the following error while upgrading pip in python

Tags: python, installation, pip

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
> [WinError 5] Access is denied:
> 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip-20.2.3.dist-info\entry_points.txt'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
>
> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is
> available. You should consider upgrading via the
> 'c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 2):

A duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115744/access-is-denied-when-trying-to-pip-install-a-package-on-windows/55100713). But here goes:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip-20.2.3.dist-info\entry_points.txt' Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.

A permission error, you can run your command prompt as an administrator or add the `--user` flag on your pip command.

> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Just a warning telling you that you have an outdated pip version.

Comment: thank you it worked when I used the  command prompt as administrator