# EnvironmentError when trying to install tensorflow-nightly in venv in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

My problem is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912999/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-de), however I don't know how to do it in my venv using PyCharm. I set up a venv in PyCharm as follows:

[image: ve]

Normally if I want to install a package I click on + search for it and install it. So tried for tensorflow-nightly. However, when trying to do so, I get the following error:

[image: e1]

Now I don't know what to do. I want to install this version into my venv. How to do that? Where should I run `pip install tf-nightly --user` to make it available in my venv? When I try to run this in PyCharm I get an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

When installing it, does this change my Python version?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Python processes running in PyCharm (debugger?) or outside of it which are using this specific venv? Looks like you do and this process is using `numpy`.

When you are trying to install tensorflow `pip` attempts to uninstall `numpy` first as the current version is not compatible with the desired `tf` version. Uninstallation clashes with the Python process which is holding some `numpy` files resulting in permission error and half working `numpy` as a result.

Check the package list, is there `~umpy` package? I remember seeing a similar issue with `matplotlib` and it manifested itself in `~atplotlib` package after a failed uninstallation attempt.

Long story short - stop all Python process running and:

- either manually remove `d:\tfexam\venv\lib\site-packages\~umpy` and install `tf` again
- or recreate the venv from the scratch

> Where should I run pip install tf-nightly --user to make it available in my venv?

You are supposed to run it in the terminal with the activated venv. Though, it is a non-relevant suggestion in this specific case. Anyway, I would suggest reading some docs about `pip` and virtualenv management if you are not familiar with them, as these topics are essential and will save you the trouble later.

Comment: "You are supposed to run it in the terminal with the activated venv." This is actually a point where something is also wrong. So I run "pip install tf-nightly" in PyCharm in my project (in my venv) as I would run normal code? Because I get an error invalid syntax. This pip command is somehow not recognized. Furthermore: No, I do not use numpy with other processes. Building it from scratch would be the very last option, as I already put some work into it installing different packages and it does take time.

Answer (score -2):

tf-nightly is an unstable version.

Use this:
pip install --upgrade tensorflow

And verify install

python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

Comment: My tensorflow is 2.2.0 and I think 2.3.0 is not yet released. And I need the nightly version.