# Install Plotnine failed in Jupyter Notebook : ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, plotnine

Dear All beloved members,

I am synat and very new to python. Mostly I used python for data sciences and recently installed plotnine module in Jupyter Notebook, but did not work.

I used the following code

```
!pip install plotnine
```

and the output I got is in the following

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-1.0.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Could any memeber suggest me some solution. I uderstand this might be a similar question, but I have tried many solutions and still did not work.

Kind Regards,

Synat,

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912999/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-de)

Comment: Hi Jia, I have seen this and went through the answers and codes. Not really worked for me.

Comment: Hi Jia, problem solved today by running the code in anaconda prompt and run as administrator as Im using university computer.