# Not able to upgrade pip on windows 10

Tags: python, pip

Error message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-20.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Can anyone solve this error?

Comment: It's probably the same error that happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912999/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-de).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912999/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-de)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use this command?

`python -m pip install -U pip --user`