# error while importing "wikipedia module" in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x

(venv) D:\Jarvis>pip install wikipedia
Collecting wikipedia
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/35/25e68fbc99e672127cc6fbb14b8ec1ba3dfef035bf1e4c90f78f24a80b7d/wikipedia-1.4.0.tar.gz
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/5d/3260694a59df0ec52f8b4883f5d23b130bc237602a1411fa670eae12351e/beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 (from wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting soupsieve>=1.2 (from beautifulsoup4->wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/a5/7ea40d0f8676bde6e464a6435a48bc5db09b1a8f4f06d41dd997b8f3c616/soupsieve-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1b/b853c7a9d4f6a6d00749e94eb6f3a041e342a885b87340b79c1ef73e3a78/certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/60/247f23a7121ae632d62811ba7f273d0e58972d75e58a94d329d51550a47d/urllib3-1.25.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, certifi, urllib3, chardet, idna, requests, wikipedia
  Running setup.py install for wikipedia ... done
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mi8vmwb5\install-record.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

**Exception:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       os.unlink(fullname)
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-el1ufi7c\wikipedia\build\lib\wikipedia\exceptions.py'

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 436, in run
>       requirement_set.cleanup_files()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\req\req_set.py", line 197, in cleanup_files
>       req.remove_temporary_source()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\req\req_install.py", line 371, in remove_temporary_source
>       rmtree(self.source_dir)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
>       return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
>       raise attempt.get()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
>       six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
>       attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\misc.py", line 121, in rmtree
>       onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 500, in rmtree
>       return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\misc.py", line 133, in rmtree_errorhandler
>       func(path)
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-el1ufi7c\wikipedia\build\lib\wikipedia\exceptions.py'

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 437, in run
>       wheel_cache.cleanup()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 60, in **exit**
>       self.cleanup()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 83, in cleanup
>       rmtree(self.path)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
>       return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
>       raise attempt.get()
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
>       six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
>       attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\misc.py", line 121, in rmtree
>       onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 500, in rmtree
>       return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 390, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>     File "C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>     File "D:\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip_internal\utils\misc.py", line 133, in rmtree_errorhandler
>       func(path)
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\dp49814\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-el1ufi7c\beautifulsoup4\beautifulsoup4-4.7.1.dist-info\COPYING.txt'

Comment: Try to improve this if you want anyone to actually read it (e.g., don't just dump your entire error).

Comment: The error is clear. What have you tried so far...?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the error message, big chance the error is permission-related.
Have you checked this link:
[python permission issue on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)