# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:

Tags: python

My python is 3.7.4. I just want to upgrade pip, then I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\SHENSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-3g065r3k\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

In case of windows, in cmd try to run pip install using python executable

e.g.

```
python -m pip install package
```

this should work, at least it worked for me for other package installation.

Comment: Applying your answer, using the python executable directly (along with administrative mode) did the trick when a normal pip install was failing. Thanks for the suggestion.