# Can't install pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm having trouble to install pyinstaller:
- windows 
- visual code 
- platform IO
- python 3.7

pip install pyinstaller
give the following error:
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/c9/c3f9bc64eb11eee6a824686deba6129884c8cbdf70e750661773b9865ee0/PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\NICK~1.VER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-fd9vckxm\PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz'
Check the permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the command as Administrator. Currently you don't have privilege to download to your Temp appdata folder presumably due to running it before as Administrator