# installing virtual environment in windows 10

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I was trying to install a virtual environment in windows and I am getting the following error message. I tried googling it but wasn't much of any help.[image: error message while installing virtual env]

Comment: Seems, you do not have access right to that (last) shown path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the problem correctly.
You can try

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

If that fails, all you need to do is either start cmd as admin, which probably some people will advise against, or use the --user flag, to install the pip package.

Comment: To add to this, you could have found the solution here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows This thread also has other options that might have worked.