# unable to install pip package for tensorflow (Gives permission denied)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, rasa, anaconda3

I am trying install rasa package on a windows 10 PC as user on my office laptop

Things tried:

1. pip install rasa
2. pip install --user rasa
3. tried in anaconda prompt in admin mode
4. login as administrator and tried in both cmd and conda prompt
5. tried by creating a new env in both cmd and conda environment
6. Tried opening python or anaconda installation folder and changed the security permission to give access to all users

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\krishnamurth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\aws\aws-cpp-sdk-s3\include\aws\s3\model\GetObjectTorrentRequest.h'
> Check the permissions.

But everything leads to a same issue (i.e tries to fetch a aws file from tensorflow directory and fails).  I also see that the tensorflow module never gets installed. So I tried `pip install tensorflow` with the above combinations and I get a different error

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\aws\aws-cpp-sdk-s3\include\aws\s3\model\ObjectTorrentRequest.h' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows

Comment: see if this helps

Comment: Sudo goes brrrr: `sudo python -m pip install rasa`

Comment: @RocketNikita i am using windows

Comment: @AliTahir thanks for the link, i tried and still getting the same issue

Comment: runas goes brrr: `runas /user:Administrator "python -m pip install rasa"`

Comment: You might not be using latest pip version. Check the `pip --version`. And also try running `pip install --user tensorflow`. Thanks!