# Still on ML-Flow installation in R Studio

Tags: r, mlflow

Please, after I load the mlflow library in R Studio and I run `install_mlflow(python_version = "3.6")` on my windows 10 machine, I get the following message printed in my console, which seems to indicate that all requirements are already satisfied:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mlflow==1.19.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.17.3 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: alembic<=1.4.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docker>=4.0.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: querystring-parser in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-flask-exporter in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.7.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.4.23)
Requirement already satisfied: gitpython>=2.1.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (3.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: waitress in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: databricks-cli>=0.8.7 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (0.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from mlflow==1.19.0) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-editor>=0.3 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from alembic<=1.4.1->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Mako in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from alembic<=1.4.1->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from alembic<=1.4.1->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.7.7 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli>=0.8.7->mlflow==1.19.0) (0.8.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli>=0.8.7->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client>=0.32.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from docker>=4.0.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32==227 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from docker>=4.0.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (227)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from gitpython>=2.1.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (4.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from gitpython>=2.1.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (3.10.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap<5,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->gitpython>=2.1.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->mlflow==1.19.0) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->mlflow==1.19.0) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from sqlalchemy->mlflow==1.19.0) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from Flask->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from Flask->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from Flask->mlflow==1.19.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->Flask->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from Werkzeug>=2.0->Flask->mlflow==1.19.0) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.0->mlflow==1.19.0) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from packaging->mlflow==1.19.0) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\ifeanyi\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-mlfl~1.0\lib\site-packages (from prometheus-flask-exporter->mlflow==1.19.0) (0.11.0)
[1] "mlflow==1.19.0"
```

Nevertheless, when I run an API call, such as `mlflow_ui()`, I still get the error message printed in my console:

```
Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), pty,  : 
  Command 'C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0/mlflow' not found @win/processx.c:982 (processx_exec)
```

Also, after loading the library and I run `install_mlflow()`, the code runs until it returns the error message in my console:

```
Error: Error installing package(s): "mlflow==1.20.3"
```

I have anaconda installed on my machine, which I believe should take care of conda installation. Please I do not know where to go from here guys.

Answer (score 0):

mlflow is installed in C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0/Scripts. That's why it can not be found.

Two ways to solve this.

1. use Sys.setenv() to set mlflow_bin to 'C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0/Scripts'

```
Sys.setenv(MLFLOW_BIN=system("which mlflow"))
Sys.setenv(MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN=system("which python"))
```

2. manually move mlflow.exe from C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0/Scripts to C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will give it a try

Comment: Hi Ian, I manually moved mlflow.exe just as you recommended. However, when I run install_mlflow("3.6"), I get the error message below:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==1.20.3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlflow==1.20.3
Error: Error installing package(s): "mlflow==1.20.3"

Comment: It also lists versions:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==1.20.3 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.9.0.1, 0.9.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1.dev0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2)

Comment: what if you just run install_mlflow(), without the specific python version.

Comment: why it tries to install 1.20.3 while the latest mlflow version is 1.20.2?

Comment: I ran install_mlflow() alone without any version, and I got the same message in my console. I do not know why it is trying to install version 1.20.3. Could it be because I tried to install the development version from Git?

Comment: I removed the package and reinstalled it from CRAN. Now I got a new message in my console after running intsall_mlflow()

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==1.20.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlflow==1.20.2
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: there seems something with you miniconda pip installation. 'from versions:none', so no version available. i guess you can try to install SSL module first.

Comment: Please how do I install SSL on Windows?

Comment: try this ````pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org```` the details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestion in the command line, but I got the error below:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\IFEANYI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-77aq1e39\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Hi, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows) to fix your access denied error.